# jpa select from two tables without relation

Tags: jpql

I have two jpa entities. Say A and B. A and B doesn't have any relation. Both of them have a common column "id". This id of A and id of B are completely different in the sense they are not related to each other.

Consider A:

### id   col1   col2

1     g    l

5     h    p

Consider B:

### id col3 col4 col5

2   p     h   i

7   j     l   k

Now I should get a list consisting of both A and B entities sorted by their id values like below. Also need a extra new column that signifies its type:

type A 1 g 1

type B 2 p h i

type A 5 h p

type B 7 j l k

So this list should be returned in a result set and I should be able to add each resultant entity into its own respective list of A and B entity type finally.Can any one please help me with a query accomplish this. How should we do this through jpql?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is good design but what you can do it is have a marker class and use that to have id and then have A & B extending marker class and use marker class to combine them.

Code Snippet:

Marker Class :

```
public class MarkerClass {
   private int id;

   public int getId() {
      return id
   }
  // you need to implement a hash code and equals here
  // you can have other common fields here
}
```

Class A :

```
public class A extends MarkerClass {
    private String col1;
    private String col2;
    ....
    // getters for them
}
```

Class B

```
public class B extends MarkerClass {
    private String col1;
    private String col2;
    ....
    // getters for them
}
```

Now you can combine them like

```
List< MarkerClass > listOfAllAAndB = new ArrayList();
listOfAllAAndB.addAll(allA);
listOfAllAAndB.addAll(allB);
Collections.sort(listOfAllAAndB, myCustomComparator);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding :) .. but I need help with query to accomplish this. Any jpql or views or stored procedure kind of thing.